# Can't quite parse these sentences

Tags: parsing

I'm reading an interview with a manga artist and having trouble making sense out of this part:

> 漫画家が集まって酒飲んだりすると、アシスタントの愚痴ばっかりですよ。ぶつぶつぶつぶつ。おなじ部屋でアシスタントをおだてて、なだめすかして、いま俺、言い過ぎたかなあなんて思いながら二時間ぐらい過ぎたりしてます。いまのは俺が悪い、いや、あいつのほうが悪いだろう、とか。

I get the first part just fine, but after the ぶつぶつ part I can't quite work out what he's saying. A little help, anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> おなじ部屋でアシスタントをおだてて、なだめすかして、『いま俺、（アシスタントに対して）言い過ぎたかなあ』なんて思いながら二時間ぐらい過ぎたりしてます。『いまのは俺が悪い』、『いや、あいつ（←アシスタント）のほうが悪いだろう』、とか（思いながら）。

こんなのでいいでしょうか・・・

Comment: 読点はかぎ括弧の外が良いんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: @broccoliforest そうですね～　直しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: That helps a little, but I'm still not entirely sure how to understand it. Is he saying that he tends to feel guilty about complaining about his assistants when drinking and is very flattering to them, say, the next day at work?

Comment: No, he's not feeling guilty. He's saying "We all manga artists always grumble about our assistants when we drink together", because they share their feelings. "おなじ部屋でアシスタントをおだてて、なだめすかして、いま俺、言い過ぎたかなあなんて思いながら二時間ぐらい過ぎたりしてます。いまのは俺が悪い、いや、あいつのほうが悪いだろう、とか。" is stating why he feels like grumbling; in the same room he needs to be fluttering to them and talks to himself 'It was my fault,' 'No it was his fault' etc but can't actually say that to them being afraid of hurting their feelings, so that's why he grumbles about them when he drinks with other manga artists.

Comment: The main topic of this passage is not that he grumbles about his assistant, but how they manga artists are usually feeling about their assistants.